# adding image in UILabel in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i have UIlabel with image.my text are won't come into top of the image i want to show my text in top of the image.

```
image1.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"salarytax.png"]];
```

this is my code to adding image to label. this image is a output of that code. how can i show the text in top of the image [image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by top? above the image or talking of alignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding the `UILabel` on the image

```
[myimageview addSubView: myLabel];
[myImageView bringSubviewToFront: myLabel];
```

If you have just taken the `UILabel` and trying to set its background as an image then dont think it would create a problem.

If you are able to view the text on the label but you want the text to be vertically on top then you can set its `contentVerticalAlignment` property to top.

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

```
UILabel *imageLabel;

[imageLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]]];
    [imageLabel setText:@"Khalid Usman"];
    [imageLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Note: I have checked it for conformation then i post. It's working.

Comment: If you check out the image he posted.. you can see that he is getting the text on the image.. So the issue was he wanted it to be vertically alligned to top :)